# For 'also', how is ' the demonstrative sense of "similarly" weakened to "in addition to" '?

Tags: etymology, old-english

> [also (adv.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=also&allowed_in_frame=0)
>       Old English *eallswa* "just as, even as, as if, so as, likewise," compound of [all](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=all&allowed_in_frame=0) + [so](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=so&allowed_in_frame=0). The demonstrative sense of "similarly" **weakened to** "in addition to" in 12c., replacing [eke](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eke&allowed_in_frame=0). [...]

Since 'similarly' is an adverb, but I didn't understand how adverbs could be demonstrative, I [Googled "demonstrative adverb"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22demonstrative+adverb%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22demonstrative+adverb%22&start=10), which advanced [p 74](https://books.google.com/books?id=TxTEzcS3vIgC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=demonstrative+adverbs&source=bl&ots=TV_N8zPMp1&sig=iT1Qa66wIX9G1FI8_qDExk6fSPI&hl=en&ei=4socSqXlHY3EMeS1hZAP&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=demonstrative%20adverbs&f=falseexplains) of *Demonstratives: Form, Function, and Grammaticalization*
(by Holger Diessel), which explains 'demonstrative adverbs'.

However, what does '**weakened**' above mean? 'Similarly' implies a comparison of two similar things, but 'in addition to' implies the introduction or adduction of something new or different.
So should **weakened to** be replaced by **strengthened to**?